# Groovy doesn't start on Windows 7 64

Tags: windows, groovy

If I type `groovy` in `cmd`, nothing happens. I can see new process `find.exe` that consumes 25% of CPU time for 30 minutes. If I kill it the console will display

> ERROR: `JAVA_HOME` is set to invalid directory: `$CORRECT_JDK_PATH`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue.
Native launcher is 32 bit executable and it cannot load 64-bit JVM :
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-222

I use groovyconsole.bat

Answer (score 0):

Basically , just point you JAVA_HOME environment variable to your jdk folder, not jre folder.
In order to run groovy needs the JDK, not the JRE, so just make sure you have a JDK installed, and then make sure you JAVA_HOME var is set to the correct folder.

Oh , and don't forget to run a new cmd window after you change the JAVA_HOME var for it to take effect.

Comment: as I sad the path is ok - it points to JDK, not JRE. The problem in find.exe or something else - it doesn't response

Answer (score 0):

Your `JAVA_HOME` is wrong, because put on `$CORRECT_JDK_PATH` string instead of the path...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem uninstall Groovy and downloaded Binary version, then go into "properties" from computer, it open the control panel, on the sidebar, select "Advanced System Settings" and click "Environment Variables", search "GROOVY_HOME" click "Edit" and change the location by your decompile groovy. I recommend in   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.5\bin" and select 'OK'.